# Scala - use companion object as shorthand argument to function accepting block

Tags: scala, case-class

I have a set of model objects and a set of wrapper objects to give them extra functionality.

I'd like to be able to convert collections of model objects to wrapper objects concisely, using the same shorthand that allows you to write `List("x", "y", "z").foreach(println)`, like this:

```
class Model
class ModelWrapper(val m: Model)
object ModelWrapper { def apply(model: Model) = new ModelWrapper(model) }

val m1 = new Model; val m2 = new Model; val m3 = new Model

List(m1, m2, m3).map(ModelWrapper)
```

So that `ModelWrapper`, passed as an argument, is converted to `ModelWrapper(_)`, a call on the companion object.

However, when I try this, I get a type mismatch error like this:

```
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : ModelWrapper.type (with underlying type object ModelWrapper)
 required: Model => ?
                  List(m1, m2, m3).map(ModelWrapper)
```

*However*, if I make `ModelWrapper` a `case class`, and remove the companion object, it works. I don't want to make it a case class as the behaviour it's adding does not fit well with the overall way in which case classes work. Two wrapper classes with the same model class as a parameter are not necessarily equal, for example.

What I'd like to know is, what is the difference between the case class and companion object in this case? Can I get what I want without using a case class?

Comment: I'd open a ticket about it. The behavior looks suspiciously inconsistent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your companion object must be a function:

```
object ModelWrapper extends Function1[Model, ModelWrapper] { def apply(model: Model) = new ModelWrapper(model) }
```

Or may be you'll prefer this abbreviation:

```
object ModelWrapper extends (Model => ModelWrapper) { def apply(model: Model) = new ModelWrapper(model) }
```

Comment: The funny things is that, according to the scala specification, the built-in companion object does not implements the Function trait. Maybe there's another explanation.

Comment: This works so marking it as accepted, thanks. But I would be interested in knowing what causes the difference. Complete guess, but I wonder if the built-in companion object does something like providing an implicit conversion to a `Function`?

Comment: I found this behavior some days ago and it was strange for me too.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, these works:

```
  List(m1, m2, m3).map(ModelWrapper(_))
  List(m1, m2, m3).map(ModelWrapper.apply)
```

It seems for *case* classes, since the companion object is created by the compiler and not you, it knows you are referring to `ModelWrapper.apply`. When there is a companion, it thinks you are referring to the companion.

Comment: Yes, this is the nub of the problem I'm having.